# How let parent window handle OleDragDrop messages if the child window can't handle them?

Tags: c++, mfc, oledragdrop

I have a parent view (:CView) which hosts several components (: CWnd). 
Components have a COleDropTarget member which gets registerd during control creation. Up to here, all works fine.

I have then added and registered an COleDropTarget in the parent CView. My hope was to receive OnDragOver messages whenever the child windows refused to deal with the dragged object by returning DROPEFFECT_NONE. But it doesn't work.
The parent view gets called only if the child control don't register himself as an oletarget.

What is the proper MFC way to let the dragdrop messages pass through the windows hierarchy?

Comment: Did you checked OnDragEnter. This function is called first.

Comment: yes I checked all.

Comment: Try and read the OLE/COM Docs. I suppose that this messages you want don't exist at all. Try to set break points on a lower level  in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\src\mfc\oledrop2.cpp. See thios and others. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleidl/nf-oleidl-idroptarget-dragover

Comment: I've already read all the docs - also this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/drag-and-drop-implementing-a-drop-target?view=vs-2017
no one describes what happens if you return 'DROPEFFECT_NONE'. The constant docs says just "Drop target cannot accept the data"